# How to Obfuscate only one class in android(eclipse)

Tags: obfuscation, android-proguard

I am very new to this proguard concept. I want to obfuscate only one file from my project, here the step that i followed to do proguard.

Setp 1: Inside project.properties, Enabled proguard.congig

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-22
android.library.reference.1=..\\Librarys\\lib1
android.library.reference.2=..\\Librarys\\lib2
android.library.reference.3=..\\Librarys\\lib3
android.library.reference.4=..\\Librarys\\lib4
android.library.reference.5=../../../../lib5
```

Step 2:
In proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class !com.myapp.initialClass.HelloWorld{ *; }
```

Here com.myapp.initialClass is my package name and HelloWorld is my java class.i.e., path is like this com/myapp/initalClass/HelloWorld.java

I am trying to test proguard file by file. How can i achieve it?